# Регулярное выражение с набором разрешенных значений

Tags: c#, linux, регулярные-выражения, веб-программирование

Возможно ли в рамках одной регулярки реализовать следующее:

Есть строка в которую пользователь может вводить все что угодно, но есть одно НО!

Есть перечень слов, которые должны употребляться только с определенной цифрой:

20 гв
30 гв
45 гв

Т.е если юзер ввел строчку: 123 qwe 20 гв. Все ок. Совпадение есть

Если юзер вбил 100500 гв 123 qwe, то совпадений нет, так сочетание 100500 гв отсутствует в списке.
Слова могут идти в произвольном порядке.

Реально ли это сделать в виде 1 регулярки?

Comment: `/(20 гв)|(30 гв)|(45 гв)/`?

Comment: Такая регулярка найдет совпадение только 20 гв в строке                  123 qwe 20 гв, а мне нужно, что бы вся строка являлась совпавшей.

Comment: `/(.*(20 гв|30 гв|45 гв).*)/`

Comment: гв может и не присутствовать в строке, как следствие если гв нет в строке, тогда вся строка должна совпадать. Если сделать перечисление разрешенных гв необязательным, тогда любая строка будет совпадать.

Comment: Эта задача не для регулярных выражений.Она элементарно решается через обычный поиск подстроки в строке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хочу пояснить и дополнить [ответ Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426913/182344).

Более правильный ответ:

```
^((20|30|45)\s+гв\b|(?!\bгв\b).)*$
```

- `(20|30|45)\s+гв` дает совпадение в строках, где за "20", "30" или "45" следует пустое пространство, а затем - "гв"
- `(?!гв).` дает совпадение на одном любом символе, если с него не начинается "гв"

`\b` добавлены, чтобы не было ложных негативных срабатываний, например на словах "гвардия" или "агв" (давайте считать, что это слово). Этому выражению удовлетворяет граница слова (`\w+`), при этом оно не поглащает символ.

Когда мы сочетаем их через комбинатор "или", получившаяся регулярка пытается заглотить оба одновременно: если встречается 2, 3 или 4, он идет по первой ветви, иначе - по второй. При этом если встречается "гв", то строка отвергается (negative lookahead).

Наконец, поскольку удовлетворяющих выражению подстрок может быть несколько (в частности, вторая ветвь "или" поглощает только один символ), а также строка может быть пустой, все выражение заключается в `^(…)*$`.

[image: Скриншот с примером]

Comment: "`(?!гв).` дает совпадение на одном любом символе, если перед ним нигде не встречается "гв"" - правильно было бы "дает совпадение на одном любом символе, если с него не начинается сочетание "гв"". Перед там что угодно может быть.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, поправлю

Comment: Лень вникать в суть вопроса, но у меня складывается ощущение, что все ответы даны в виде очень странных регулярных выражений, которые неоправданно сложны и малопроизводительны. Верно ли, что выражение `/^.*(20|30|45)\s+гв\b.*$/isu` полностью решает задачу ?

Comment: @ReinRaus, неверно. Это написано в одном из комментариев к вопросу. Сочетание с "гв" вообще не обязано находиться в строке. А по поводу производительности - не вижу в своей (а так же в дополненной границами слова) регулярке ничего непроизводительного. Там всё линейно же. Отката больше чем на несколько символов назад не будет никогда.

Comment: @ReinRaus, да, твоя регулярка примерно на 16% шустрее, но, как я уже сказал, она не соответствует задаче. `var regs = [/^((20|30|45)\s+гв\b|(?!\bгв\b).)*$/, /^.*(20|30|45)\s+гв\b.*$/], r, q;
for(q=0; q<regs.length; ++q) {
  console.time(r=regs[q]);
  for(w=0; w<1000000; ++w) r.test("что-то 20 гв ещё тут"), r.test("20 гв текст текст текст текст"), r.test("текст текст текст текст 20 гв");
  console.timeEnd(r);
}`, вывод: `/^((20|30|45)\s+гв\b|(?!\bгв\b).)*$/: 2132.354ms`
`/^.*(20|30|45)\s+гв\b.*$/: 1804.840ms`

Comment: Обе выполняются мгновенно, да и вообще, регулярки не используют там, где нужно позарез оптимизировать производительность. Они скорее некое универсальное средство, либо простое, прозрачное решение.

Comment: @Qwertiy `/^.*(?:(20|30|45)\s+гв\b)?.*$/isu` ок. Теперь сочетания может и не быть. В той регулярке дело не в откатах. На каждый символ проверяется несколько условий: `(20|30|45)\s+гв\b` и `(?!\bгв\b)` Эти два подвыражения проверяются всегда для каждого символа текста.

Comment: @Qwertiy меня больше удивила сложность выражения, чем производительность.

Comment: @ReinRaus, последний вариант неверный. `/^.*(?:(20|30|45)\s+гв\b)?.*$/.test("1000 гв")` выводит `true` - мы говорим что возможно что-то есть, но фактически первая `.*` сжирает всё, кусок с вопросом мапится на пустую строку, последняя `.*` тоже пустая. Сорри, не в курсе, что за флаг `s`.

Comment: Кстати, мы по идее должны же для шарпа обсуждать, а там можно проверить на `гв` и сделать предпросмотр назад - возможно, будет немного шустрее, хотя браузеру такое уже не скормить.

Comment: Посмотрел про `s` - он не повлияет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, извините. Мне все показалось неоправданно сложным, но ТС выразил свою волю, что `мне нужно, что бы вся строка являлась совпавшей`, хотя нужно было бы регулярку `\b(20|30|45)\s+гв\b` применять к тексту и смотреть есть ли вообще совпадения, а не делать всю строку совпадением.

Comment: @ReinRaus не забывайте, что нужно также отлавливать случаи вроде "666 гв", которые нарушают условия (гв может употребляться только с тремя числами), при этом в строке могут быть и допустимые употребления "гв".

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko простите. С такими условиями все весьма целесообразно.

Comment: @ReinRaus, вообще, я не вижу явного требования, что строка может содержать одновременно несколько значений с "гв". А вообще, по тегам возникает подозрение, что регулярка будет скормлена соответствующему атрибуту для автоматической проверки.

Answer (score 2):

Вот:

```
^((20|30|45) гв|(?!гв).)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно ли присутствие числа перед "гв"?

Если нет, то ищите все вхождения `(?<count>\d+)\w+гв` в строке - а потом уже вне регулярки проверяйте найденную группу `count` по списку разрешенных значений.

Если число перед "гв" обязательно, используйте регулярку `(?<count>\d*)\w+гв`.